# What is the difference between addTarget(_:action:for:) and sendAction(_:to:for:) UIControl instance methods?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uicontrol

I am subclassing `UIControl` and as I wanted to set my view controller as the target, I discovered the sendAction method. I can't really figure out the differences between both methods and when their respective usage is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that [`sendAction(_:to:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction) actually **calls** the defined selector right away, while [`addTarget(_:action:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) only **associates** a target and action with the control and only calls the selector when the event happens.

Comment: In other words, the implementation of your `UIControl` subclass calls `sendAction` to notify anyone listening for the event. The users of your custom control call `addTarget`. Your custom control implementation will not make use of `addTarget`, only `sendAction`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `sendAction:to:forEvent:` to simulate an actual, under-the-hood system call. ie: Simulating a user actually tapping a `UIButton` (a `UIControl`) and sending the `UIControlEvents` `touchUpInside` to the target. I've personally never had to use it before.

`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` maps the Selector, `UIControlEvent` and Target, to be used at a later time, such as when a user taps a `UIButton`.